# FutureBuilder keeps executing when navigating between pages using Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a bottom navigation bar from my MaterialApp and one of the pages use FutureBuilder to retrieve data from my RESTful API. My bottom navigation bar needs to save the state of the pages, So I came across [this guide](https://medium.com/@lucassaltoncardinali/keeping-state-with-the-bottom-navigation-bar-in-flutter-69e4168878e1) on how to keep the state of my bottom navigation bar using PageStorage.

The issue I have encountered is that whenever I navigate out of the FutureBuilder page and back again, it rebuilds the entire page and re-executes my Future method.

I also read [another guide](https://medium.com/saugo360/flutter-my-futurebuilder-keeps-firing-6e774830bc2) on using AsyncMemoizer to run my Future method only once (It still rebuilds the page, but much faster). The snippet of code below is how I have implemented it.

```
//Unsure why AsyncMemoizer somehow only works if I use StatelessWidget, and not StatefulWidget
class FuturePage extends StatelessWidget {

    /*I had to comment this constructor out because AsyncMemoizer must be
      initialised with a constant value */
    //const FuturePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

    //To store my PageStorageKey into bucket
    FuturePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

    final _memoizer = new AsyncMemoizer();

     _fetchData() => this._memoizer.runOnce(_myFutureMethod);

    Future<MyType> _myFutureMethod() async => print("Executed"); //await post and return data

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _fetchData(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  //set up my widgets
              }
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
        );
    }
}
```

On the output log, `Executed` is only displayed once. However, I need to use a StatefulWidget instead of StatelessWidget, and AsyncMemoizer wouldn't work in my case.

```
class FuturePage extends StatefulWidget {

    FuturePageState createState() => FuturePageState();

    const FuturePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
}
```

How do I save the state of my FutureBuilder Page using StatefulWidget? I'm still relatively new to flutter and the concepts of reactive programming. Sincerest apologies if I happen to be doing something wrongly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this behavior you can use the **AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin**

```
class FuturePage extends StatefulWidget {

     const FuturePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

     @override
     FuturePageState createState() => FuturePageState();
}
```

You need to implement  **AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin**

```
class FuturePageState extends State<FuturePage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<FuturePage>{

   @override
   bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   super.build(context); // call super method
   return // Your Widget 
  }

}
```

Comment: Are u sure this will work?